# how listen for taps on bash

Tags: android, bash, shell, termux

On Android, sometimes I use [w3m](https://github.com/acg/w3m) (a text base browser) on [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)

it listens for taps and reacts to the tap

I would like to know how can I write a bash script to listen to the tap[/*tap position*] and react to it, like a webpage with multiple intents/links[which redirects to multiple web pages]

Comment: *'toolbox getevent -il'* will give you base to start. once you figured out you can listen *'toolbox getevent -l /dev/input/event'*

Comment: What do you mean 'listens for taps"? You mean click/touch events?